# Grunt Watch repeatedly showing "Warning: must provide pattern"

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-connect

I'm having trouble configuring Grunt to watch my project files, rebuild and update a page hosted in a connect server. If I run any of the build tasks and then `'watch'` as part of a combined task, then `'watch'` seems to get stuck in a loop, endlessly printing the message.

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Warning: must provide pattern
```

If instead I just run `$ grunt watch`, it will happily watch my source files and compile/build as appropriate.

I think the relevant task configurations are these:

```
watch: {
  html: {
    files: [ '<%= site.partials %>', '<%= site.layouts %>', '<%= site.pages %>' ],
    tasks: [ 'html' ]
  },
  sass: {
    files: [ '<%= site.src %>sass/*.scss' ],
    tasks: [ 'styles' ]
  }
},

// development server
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 8080,
    livereload: 35729,
    hostname: 'localhost',
  },
  dev: {
    options: {
      directory: 'build',
    }
  }
},
```

and the task definitions:

```
grunt.registerTask( 'build', [ 'styles', 'html', ] );
grunt.registerTask( 'default', [  'build','connect:dev', 'watch' ] );
```

The `'styles'` and `'html'` tasks run grunt-sass and assemble. As stated above, running any of these tasks, or even `'watch'` on its own yields the expected results. This suggests my config object has `site.partials`, `site.dest` etc defined correctly. The problem only happens when I run any task and then `'watch'`, as in the default task.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the templates referencing the `site` object. However, without seeing that part of your `grunt.initConfig` call, I really can't say. I know this question is old now, but can you either post your entire Gruntfile or, if you've solved the problem, post your answer?

Answer (score 17):

I just encountered a similar problem when I had been editing my Gruntfile and left a field (that should have had a file pattern) blank.

Check your Gruntfile for an empty file field.

In my specific example:

```
wiredep: {
    options: {
        overrides: {
          "jquery-ui": {
              "main": [
                 "jquery-ui.js",
                 "themes/base/jquery-ui.css",
                 ""
              ]
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Note the empty string above. That generated an error very similar to yours. It seems that Grunt doesn't tell you *where* the error is, unfortunately. You'll just need to scan through your Gruntfile manually to find the error.

Comment: Grunt really is useless at letting you know where the error is, took me ages to track it down, but it was exactly this.

Comment: In this context a string like `"<%= cfg.foo %>"` is also empty when there is no `foo` in `cfg`. This is the problem I had.

Answer (score -1):

connect:dev is the problem. Remove that and it should work fine.

Comment: `grunt-contrib-connect` is a multi-task and should be able to handle multiple targets simultaneously. Their documentation even suggests numerous examples like this. Why would a simple target with one option (an option connect needs) cause a problem?

Comment: Without further explanation, this comment is random, maybe created by a Jean-bot. The purpose of answering is to inform both the original poster and other readers. Why is `connect:dev` a problem? I suspect it is not.