# How to read an external file list with grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm trying to concatenate and then babelify and uglify files with Grunt.

I'd like to read an external file list, from a file where the files are written one for each line, newline separated.

I'm trying to use the following GruntFile.js, but Grunt says (after I added the `src=['<%= jsFiles.toString().split("\n") %>']` line):

```
Running "browserify:dist1" (browserify) task
Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (Invalid or unexpected token). Use --force to continue.
```

Where is the error?

This is the GruntFile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    jsFiles: grunt.file.read('scripts/s.list'),
    env: {
        prod: {
            NODE_ENV: 'production'
        }
    },
    browserify: {
      dist1: {
        options: {
           transform: [
             ['babelify', {presets: ['es2015']}]
           ]
        },
        src: ['<%= jsFiles.toString().split("\n") %>'],
        dest: '/WebContent/js/libs/s.bundle.js'
      },
    },
    uglify: {
        my_target1: {
          files: {
            '/WebContent/js/libs/s.bundleuglified.js': ['/WebContent/js/libs/s.bundle.js']
          }
        },
      }    
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-env');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['release']);
  grunt.registerTask('release', ['env', 'browserify', 'uglify']);
};
```

**Edit**: I added a backslash to \n and the error has gone, but the babelify task gives me an empty file...

**Edit2**: I was able to read the file list using the following two lines at the beginning of the GruntFile.js

```
  const jsFiles = grunt.file.read('scripts/s.list');
  const jsFilesArray = jsFiles.toString().split("\n");
```

and then

```
src: jsFilesArray.slice(0, jsFilesArray.length-1),
```

because the last element was '' and it gave the error [Warning: must provide pattern”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233743/grunt-watch-repeatedly-showing-warning-must-provide-pattern) as Beniamin H suggested.

**Edit3**: I found that the babelify task was reading the files in alphabetical order, so I had to first concat them, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454688/using-grunt-to-concatenate-files-in-sequence), and then babelify and uglify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use any `'<%=  %>'`. The file is read synchronously into `jsFiles` property and it can be used immediately. You may want to specify encoding for `grunt.file.read` to get a string: https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.read

Comment: So, what should I write for src in your opinion? Only src = 'jsFiles.toString().split("\n")' ?

Comment: I cannot check it now but something like this should work:   
`src: this.jsFiles.toString().split("\n"),`

Comment: this gives `>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
`

Comment: Ahh - yes, you may read a file to a variable, not into config object.
`const jsFiles = grunt.file.read('scripts/s.list');`
and then:
`src: jsFiles.toString().split("\n")`

Comment: You can do it the first line of the function.

Comment: This way it works if I put two backslashes before n, but unfortunately I get an empty bundle - with a single backslash I get this error : `Warning: must provide pattern`

Comment: Probably you need to specify `dist1` for your browserify task: `grunt.registerTask('release', ['env', 'browserify:dist1', 'uglify']);`

Comment: Or omit wrapping browserify options into `dist1`:
```browserify: {
        options: {...},
        src: ...
      },```

Comment: About _"Warning: must provide pattern"_: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233743/grunt-watch-repeatedly-showing-warning-must-provide-pattern

Comment: The file was ok, I was able to read the file list as I explain in Edit2. Thank you for the link to the must provide pattern error. Unfortunately it seems the file list is being read in a different order that the one I specify.